# Laravel - Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an application using Angular-7 as frontend and Laravel-5.8. I am using Laravel Spatie for User Management. I have these three tables:

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `client_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `trips` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `dispatch_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `loading_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `loaded_from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

From the tables above, I have three classes: User, Client and Trip. I have used Laravel Spatie to enable users to only have access to data they are given permission. This is working perfectly.

Now, I want to achieve the following from the ApiController:

1. The Logged-in user should be able to view only the trips that his client embark on.
2. If the Logged-In user belongs to the Client that has client_id as MBB, he should be able to view all the trips for all the clients in the database, except he doesn't have permission to view trips.

```
    public function index(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userClientId = Auth::user()->client_id;

        if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('View Trip')){
            return response()->json([ "message" => 'User do not have permission'], 401);
        }

        try{  

            if(Auth::user()->client_id == 'MBB')
            {      
                if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='') && $request->get('search')){
                    $trip = Trip::where("trip_number", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
                } else if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='')){
                    $trip = Trip::orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
                }
                else if($request->get('search'))
                    $trip = Trip::where("trip_number", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->paginate(10);
                else
                    $trip = Trip::paginate(10);
            }
            else 
            {
                $trip = Trip::where('client_id', $userClientId)
                if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='') && $request->get('search')){
                    $trip = $trip->where("trip_number", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
                } else if(($request->get('sort')!='null' && $request->get('sort')!='')){
                    $trip = $trip->orderby($request->get('sort'), $request->get('order'))->paginate(10);
                } else if($request->get('search')) {
                    $trip = $trip->where("trip_number", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('search')}%")->paginate(10);
                } else{
                    $trip = $trip->paginate(10);
                }

            }
            return response()->json($trip, 200);
        }
        catch(QueryException $e)
        {

            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];

            return response()->json($errorCode);
        }
    }
```

When I loaded the page, I got this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Then when I clicked on the error in the console, it took me to this page on Laravel:

[image: syntax error]

So, I observe that the error is from the else statement (Line 56 from the diagram, where I highlighted yellow) where the client_id is not MBB. I looked at the statement and couldn't see anything wrong.
How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon in line 55. Unexpected errors refer to syntax errors in most cases

```
$trip = Trip::where('client_id', $userClientId);
                                               ^^
```